# REST: How to handle POST request which already has ID in request body

Tags: rest, api-design

We have product with rest endpoint POST, PUT, DELETE.

The POST request body looks like:

```
{
      "Id": Unique identifier of the product,
      "Description": Product description,
      "Price": Price of the product
}
```

Now, since POST is considered to be Non-Idempotent, but here we can't allow duplicate entries with same "Id". This "Id" in request body is third party system Id which POST request to our system.

We allow the resource to be updated/deleted with this "Id" only and do not expect POST/PUT with our internal generated Ids. Although we generate our unique Id which we send back in response of this POST request just as acknowledgement that request was processed.

But I was wondering, should it be POST or a PUT request? What should we do in case we get duplicate POST request, we should send back validation error OR update the previous saved request?

What does REST say OR which approach would be better for performance and maintenance?

Answer (score 1):

Why not offer both?

A `POST` method which throws a [HttpStatusCode](http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/) 409 (Conflict) in case the id in the body is already present in your system, and another one (`PUT`), that updates the resource with the new values in the body. You can even add a [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902), for only updating the fields passed in the body.